# Equivalent Characterizations of Trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

First some definitions:

> An edge path, or more simply a path, in a graph consists of an alternating sequence of vertices and edges $\{v_0,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n\}$ where $Ends(e_i) = \{v_{i-1},v_i\}$.

---

> A *backtrack* is a path of the form $\{v,e,w,e,v\}$. A path is *reduced* if it contains no backtracks

---

> A *cycle* or *circuit* is a nontrivial edge path whose first and last vertices are the same, but not other vertex is repeated.

---

> A *tree* is a connected graph with no cycles.

---

> **Exercise 1.10.** Prove that the following conditions on a connected graph $\Gamma$ are equivalent.
>
> 1. $\Gamma$ is a tree.
> 2. Given any two vertices $v$ and $w$ in $\Gamma$, there is a unique reduced edge
>    from $v$ to $w$
> 3. For every edge $e \in E(\Gamma)$, removing $e$ from $\Gamma$ disconnects the graph. (Note: Removing $e$ does not remove its associated vertices.)
> 4. If $\Gamma$ is finite, then $\# V(\Gamma) = \# E(\Gamma) + 1$

I am just trying to show 1,2, and 3 are equivalent; but I am having some trouble. I am looking for a critique and help with finishing some of the proofs. Here's what I have so far:

**First we prove (1) implies (2).** Let $v,w$ be vertices in the tree $\Gamma$. Because $\Gamma$ is connected, there is edge path $\{v,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,w\}$ from $v$ to $w$. Since $\Gamma$ is a tree, by definition it cannot contain cycles, so a fortiori it cannot contain any back tracks, so the edge path $\{v,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,w\}$ must be reduced. Now we prove uniqueness. By way of contradiction, suppose that $\{v,f_1,w_1,...,w_{k-1},f_k,w\}$ is another edge path between $v$ and $w$. Then reversing the path and concatenating it with the former, we obtain $\{v,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,w,f_k,w_{k-1},...,w_1,f_1,v\}$. But this is a nontrivial edge path from $v$ to $v$, that is, a cycle, so we have arrived at a contradiction.

**Now we prove (2) implies (3).** Let $e$ be some edge in the connected graph $\Gamma$. Being an edge, it must connect to vertices, call them $v$ and $w$. Clearly $\{v,e,w\}$ is a reduced path edge, since it isn't even long enough to have or be a backtrack. By (2), this is the only reduced path edge. Suppose there is another path from $v$ to $w$:

$$\{v,e_1,v_1,...,v_{i-1},e_i,v_i,e_{i+1},v_{i+1},e_{i+2},v_{i+2},...,v_{n-1},e_n,w\},$$
where $i=1,...,n$ is arbitrary. If $e_i \neq e_{i+1}$ and $v_{i-1} \neq v_{i+1}$, then, since $i$ was arbitrary, the above is a reduced path since it contains no backtracks, which is a contradiction. Hence there are multiple cases to consider. The first is that $e_i = e_{i+1}$ but $v_{i-1} = v_i$...**don't know how to deal with this case.**..The second is that $v_{i-1} = v_{i+1}$ but $e_{i} \neq e_{i+1}$. If this is the case, then $\{v_{i-1},e_i,v_i\}$ and $\{v_{i+1},e_{i+1},v_i\}$ are two different reduced edge paths between, which contradicts (2). Finally, there is the case when $v_{i-1} = v_{i+1}$ and $e_i = e_{i+1}$...and there is where we can remove something to get a reduced path (if not, continue this process to get a reduced path...?)...**not really sure how to finish this last case either**

**Now we argue (3) implies (1) contrapositively.** If $\Gamma$ is not a tree, then there is a cycle $\{v_0,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n\}$ with $v_0 = v_n$. My thought was that removing $e_n$ would be the right move, but I am not so sure...I tried this, but the problem broke up into several very complicated cases, some of which I could not solve.

**Edit:** Okay I think my proof of uniqueness in my proof of "(1) implies (2)" is okay, so let me address the concern about backtracks. Suppose that the above path has a backtrack; that is, suppose that

$$\{...v_{i-i},e_i,v_i,e_{i+1},v_{i+1},e_{i+2},v_{i+2},e_{i+3}v_{i+3}...\}$$

with $v_i = v_{i+2}$ and $e_{i+1} = e_{i+2}$. Then by removing the edges $e_{i+1}$ and $e_{i+2}$, and vertices $v_{i+1}$ and $v_{i+2}$, we obtain

$$\{...,v_{i-i},e_i,v_i,e_{i+3},v_{i+3},...\},$$

which is a valid path between $v$ and $w$ because $Ends(e_{i+3}) = \{v_i,v_{i+3}\}$. This removes the backtrack from the given path. If it contains any other backtracks, these can be removed in the same way (there will be only finitely many, if any, so this removal can be done inductively).

**Haven't worked out the other parts yet...will type them up when I get a chance.**

Comment: In (1) implies (2) the lack of cycles doesn't imply that the path that was chosen doesn't have backtracks. What you need to do is that if the path chosen has backtracks, then you can remove them.

Comment: In (2) implies (3) it looks that all you are missing is to prove that given any path, you can reduce it. This is, construct a new path with the same end-points a subset of the same edges, and no cycles or backtracks. You can do this by induction on the length of the path and number of vertices at the beginning of the path that don't contain backtracks. Every time you find an $\{v,e,w,e,v\}$, just remove it and leave only $\{v\}$. This reduces the length of the path.

Comment: (3) implies (2). Clearly $\Gamma$ is connected to begin with. Otherwise, removing any edge would disconnect the graph. If there were a cycle, you can remove any edge of the cycle and the graph doesn't disconnect, since you can travel the cycle along what remains of the cycle.

Comment: (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (4) can be proven by induction. Just prove that there must be vertices with degree $1$. Removing those reduces both the count of vertices and edges, and doesn't disconnect the graph.

Comment: @user647486 Oh, so not every backtrack is a cycle (e.g., in $\{v,e,w,e,v\}$ $w$ could be the same as $v$), which is why my proof of (1) implies (2) isn't correct?

Comment: @user647486 Also, the author says that backtracks are of the form $\{v,e,w,e,v\}$. Are there backtracks that are "longer"?

Comment: In the definition of cycle given doesn't allow repetition of vertices. That might or might not be different in other books. So, in this definition they don't consider backtracks to be cycles. Existence of cycles are a property inherent to a graph. Buck existence of backtracks are a property of paths. You can take the graph with vertices $v,w$ and one edge $e$ between them. It doesn't have cycles. But you can have a path on it going back and forth many times between those two vertices.

Comment: Note that any 'longer backtrack' is going to contain inside a section of the form $\{v,e,w,e,v\}$. at any vertex $w$ at which the path actually changes direction.

Comment: @user647486 Ah, I see....So, I tried fixing the proof of "(1) implies (2)" Would you mind checking out my edit?

Comment: It still says "by definition it cannot contain cycles, so a fortiori it cannot contain any back tracks". This is not correct. Two comments before this one I gave an example of a tree with two vertices (which in particular has no cycles) and explained how you can have many paths with backtracks on it. The problem is that if you start with a given path, there is no way (no matter the graph) to ensure that that path doesn't have backtracks. What you need to argue is that you can 'reduce the path', remove the backtracks from it.

Comment: @user647486 I'm terribly sorry. I was editing my post in a different tab and it seems that I forget to click the button to finish the edit. My edit should be there now.

Comment: Yes, something like that should be convincing enough. Of course, that should replace the 'a fortiory' part. Then it would finish by saying that this reduced path is either identical to $\{v,e,w\}$ or it doesn't contain $e$ at all, since now there are no repeated vertices in it. But then traveling the reduced path followed by $e$ in reverse would form a cycle, which contradicts (1).